# How to executed code its taking to much time and also result not come

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data shape (1315617, 23) and I was trying the below both model codes to run but this code was not executed in two days also, please let me know its need any changes in this code. No error in code but not coming result it's stuck.

```
# K-nearest neighbour
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier().fit(Xsm_train,ysm_train)
y_pred=knn_clf.predict(Xsm_test)

cm=confusion_matrix(ysm_test,y_pred)

cmd=ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm,display_labels=['Death','Live'])

cmd.plot()

print(accuracy_score(ysm_test,y_pred))

print(classification_report(ysm_test,y_pred))


# SVM regression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm_clf = SVC(probability=True, kernel = 'linear').fit(Xsm_train,ysm_train)

y_pred=svm_clf.predict(Xsm_test)

cm=confusion_matrix(ysm_test,y_pred)
cmd=ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm,display_labels=['Death','Live'])

cmd.plot()

print(accuracy_score(ysm_test,y_pred))

print(classification_report(ysm_test,y_pred))
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Kumar Saroj! You're using a SVM classifier in this example. As far as I remember, it has O(n^2) time complexity depending on the number of training instances, and it could take a long time to train, because there are more then 10e6 training instances in X_train, if I'm getting it right. So you would switch to another model, for example, SGDClassifier, which training time depends linearly on the number of training instance

Comment: When working with data that could take a long time to process, it is always a great idea to take a small subset of the data and run it through the code.  That way you can fix things with a short turn around before running your code against all the data.